# GUI input with select.select and sys.stdin in Python3 Chat

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to integrate this module to Tkinter using the Entry() function of Tkinter. However, upon integrating it, the terminal waits for an input. Without an input from terminal, the chat will not proceed on the GUI Tkinter entry window.

I believe it is cause by the "sys.stdin" in "sockets_list = [sys.stdin, socket]". I don't know what to replace sys.stdin for GUI. Please help thank you!

```
def get_chat_entry(player, packet, lobby_id, connectPacket, event=None):
    # maintains a list of possible input streams 
    sockets_list = [sys.stdin, socket] 
    #Instantiate chat packet 
    chatPacket = packet.ChatPacket()
    read_sockets,write_socket,error_socket = select.select([socket],[],[])

    for socks in read_sockets: 
        if socks == socket: 
            packet_received = bytearray(socket.recv(2048))
            packet.ParseFromString(packet_received)
            packet_type = packet.type 

            #Chat packet type
            if packet_type == 3:
                #Receive broadcasted data from server
                chatPacket.ParseFromString(packet_received)
                print(chatPacket.message) 
                #update chat_text_box
                chat_history_Txt.config(state=NORMAL)
                chat_history_Txt.insert(END, chatPacket.message + '\n')
                chat_history_Txt.see("end")
                chat_history_Txt.config(state=DISABLED)
        else: 
            # #Write your message here
            chatPacket.type = TcpPacket.CHAT
            chatPacket.message = chat_entry.get()

            socket.send(chatPacket.SerializeToString())
```

Comment: Have you considered reading a tutorial on event-driven GUI programming? "I don't know what to replace sys.stdin for GUI" is a good indicator of cargo cult programming, which does not work.

Comment: Why did you include `sys.stdin` in `sockets_list`?  The only inputs should be either from `sockets` (other members) or your input via `chat_entry`.  So remove `sys.stdin` from `sockets_list`.

Comment: yes, thank you. I'm aware that it should be removed and be replaced by chat_entry, however sockets_list only accepts file i/o. Chat_entry is not a fileI/o

Comment: I do not mean you need to add `chat_entry` into `sockets_list`.  You need to either create a new thread or use `after()` in main thread to wait for input from socket and update `chat_history_Txt`.  You also need to `bind` a function to the `chat_entry` so that whenever you has entered a message and press `Enter` key, the bind function will be executed to update `chat_history_Txt`.